# Can I run gcloud components update?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

Will updating gcloud components from within my Google Cloud Shell instance persist?

Will updating anything, like Go or NPM, that is pre-installed with Google Cloud Shell persist?

Comment: Cloud Shell VM image is updated weekly so Cloud SDK components including gcloud are at the latest version / up-to-date most of the time, you shouldn't need to update it.

For other software: anything you install at your home disk will persist as the home disk is persistent across VM instantiations.  System-wide software updates will not persist.

Comment: @AlexeyAlexandrov Thank you. I would have chosen your answer but  you posted it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, depending upon where you install those tools.

When you init a new cloud shell, you get a disk for yourself, and the system image is constructed using a template. So any changes that you do to your disk will persist, while anything you do to core image, will not.

All the pre-installed tools are part of the system image that is updated for all the users and is maintained by GCP team. If you are updating or switching versions there, they will not persist.

But if you want to install custom tools, or switch to a specific version, you can install those tools at your `$HOME`. All those tools will be installed in your disk and hence will persist across termination/relaunches.